# Making a recursive method to print a text in java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I have to make a program which works like this. first it gets a number from input and then it gets (number) * strings.

for example:

```
2
a b
```

or

```
3
x1 x2 x3
```

then in the output it prints something like this:

```
Math.max(a, b)
```

or

```
Math.max(x1, Math.max(x2, x3))
```

I want to make Math.max method syntax with this code. I hope you understood!

Another Sample Input & output:

Input =

```
4
a b c d
```

Output =

```
Math.max(a, Math.max(b, Math.max(c, d)))
```

can someone help me?

The code I've wrote for it, can you suggest me some changes to make it better?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = input.nextInt();
    String[] r = new String[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      r[i] = input.next();
    }
    printmax(r);

  }
  public static int i = 0 , j = 0;
  public static boolean last = false;
  public static void printmax(String [] r){
    if (last == true) {
      System.out.print(r[r.length - 1]);
      while (j < r.length - 1){ System.out.print(")");
        j++;
      }
    }
    if (r.length == 2) System.out.print("Math.max(" +r[0] + ", " + r[1] + ")");
    if (r.length > 2) {
      while (i < r.length -1) {
        if (i == r.length -2) last = true;
        System.out.print("Math.max(" + r[i] + ", ");
        i++;
        printmax(r);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You can't just expect someone to give you the entire answer.

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary I'm not looking for the entire answer! just need an idea how to implement it

Comment: put your inputs in an array. Now take last 2 elements of the array and form a string using StringBuffer. keep doing this recursively, by moving backwards in the array.

Comment: in a loop, add `"Math.max("`, the name and `", "`; unless one name is left which is then added followed by correct number of `")"` - recommended to use `StringBuilder` to hold the result text

Comment: @user85421 could you please send an answer to this? It will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to achieve the above, here m calling maxElement() function recursively to achieve somthing like this Math.max(a, Math.max(b, Math.max(c, d)))

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int length = 2; //here read the input from scanner
    String[] array = {"a", "b"}; //here read this input from scanner
    String max = maxElement(array,0,length);
    System.out.println(max);
}
    
public static String maxElement(String[] start, int index, int length) {
    if (index<length-1) {
        return "Math.max(" + start[index]  +  ", " + maxElement(start, index+1, length)+ ")";
    } else {
        return start[length-1];
    }
}
```

Output:
Math.max(a, b)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this.

First you define a function `maxElement` which takes your **variable array** as a parameter.

```
public static maxElement(String[] variables) {
    return maxElementBis(variables,0);
}
```

Then you call a second function : `maxElementBis` which takes an additional argument which represents the **index of the variable we are processing**.

```
public static String maxElementBis(String[] variables, int index) {
    if (variables.length < 2) 
        return "not enought variables";
    if (variables.length - index == 2)
        return "Math.max("+ variables[index]+","+variables[index + 1]+")";
    return "Math.max("+ variables[index]+","+maxElementBis(variables,index + 1)+")";

}
```

**If the array contains less than two variables** you cannot do what you want.

**If you only have two variables** left, this is your stop condition and you can directly return `Math.max(v1,v2)`.

**Otherwise** you recursively call your function `maxElementBis`.